# What is a viable infantry to armor ratio for 1935 Nazi Germany?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-3

Starting HOI3 from the very start of the Nazi German campaign, what is the ideal ratio of infantry to armor up until the invasion of Poland? How large should the armed forces be in general prior to the invasion?